# How to get iPhone Bluetooth name, Peripheral identifier , Unique bluetooth address or CBPeripheral object in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to fetch my **current running iOS application device's Bluetooth Peripheral Identifier** information for uniqueness.

Tried to get it programmatically but the CoreBluetooth framework only provides this information once we scan for other Bluetooth devices.

Can we **fetch the current device Bluetooth Name, CBPeripheral object or any other Bluetooth unique information** if Bluetooth is in ON condition ??

Comment: No you can't. And any identifier that another device sees for your device is unique for the device pair. Ie a third device will see a different identifier for your device.  The standard way to identify your device is `identifierForVendor`